# creating multiple variables in one data.table call

Tags: r, data.table

Given:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                 result = c("negative", "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "negative",
                            "positive", "negative", "positive"),
                 test_date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("01/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                                 to = as.Date("09/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), by = "day"),
                 type = c("car", "truck", "bike", "wheel", "tyre", "lorry", "car", "bike", "wheel"),
                 colour = c("gre", "blu", "re", "dblu", "yel", "re", "ora", "ti", "bla"),
                 x1 = sample(letters, 9),
                 x2 = sample(letters, 9))
df
#   id   result  test_date  type colour x1 x2
# 1  a negative 1998-01-01   car    gre  y  u
# 2  a positive 1998-01-02 truck    blu  d  z
# 3  a positive 1998-01-03  bike     re  g  j
# 4  b negative 1998-01-04 wheel   dblu  a  v
# 5  b negative 1998-01-05  tyre    yel  b  n
# 6  b negative 1998-01-06 lorry     re  k  x
# 7  c positive 1998-01-07   car    ora  n  g
# 8  c negative 1998-01-08  bike     ti  r  i
# 9  c positive 1998-01-09 wheel    bla  w  o
```

I want to extract by group, the first and last rows of certain columns and the `test_date` associated with the first occurance of `result == "positive"`. The following will work when using `dplyr`:

```
out_dplyr <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(type, colour), dplyr::first),
            across(c(x1, x2), dplyr::last),
            test_date = if (is.na(dplyr::first(test_date[result == "positive"])))
              dplyr::last(test_date[result == "negative"])
            else dplyr::first(test_date[result == "positive"])) %>% 
  ungroup()
out_dplyr
#   id    type  colour x1    x2    test_date 
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <date>    
# 1 a     car   gre    g     j     1998-01-02
# 2 b     wheel dblu   k     x     1998-01-06
# 3 c     car   ora    w     o     1998-01-07
```

I've been trying to do the same with `data.table`, the following will work if I leave out the third variable:

```
df_dt <- data.table(df)
dt_names_first <- c("type", "colour")
dt_names_last <- c("x1", "x2")
out_dt <- df_dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, dt_names_first, with = FALSE], data.table::first),
                    lapply(.SD[, dt_names_last, with = FALSE], data.table::last)), .(id)]
out_dt
#    id  type colour x1 x2
# 1:  a   car    gre  g  j
# 2:  b wheel   dblu  k  x
# 3:  c   car    ora  w  o
```

but when I include it, it fails as I think I am including it incorrectly:

```
out_dt <- df_dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, dt_names_first, with = FALSE], data.table::first),
                    lapply(.SD[, dt_names_last, with = FALSE], data.table::last),
                    test_date = if (is.na(data.table::first(test_date[result == "positive"])))
                      data.table::last(test_date[result == "negative"])
                    else data.table::first(test_date[result == "positive"])), .(id)]
out_dt
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a soluiton that rectifies the code you have or a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `all`/`any` to wrap the logical vector as `if/else` is not vectorized i.e. it expects a single `TRUE/FALSE`,  In addition, wrap the `test_date = ..` inside a `list`

```
df_dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, dt_names_first, with = FALSE], data.table::first),
              lapply(.SD[, dt_names_last, with = FALSE], data.table::last),
            list(test_date = if(all(is.na(data.table::first(test_date[
        result == "positive"]))))
        data.table::last(test_date[result == "negative"])
                    else data.table::first(test_date[result == "positive"]))),
 .(id)]
```

-output

```
   id  type colour x1 x2  test_date
1:  a   car    gre  g  j 1998-01-02
2:  b wheel   dblu  k  x 1998-01-06
3:  c   car    ora  w  o 1998-01-07
```

Comment: is `list` needed so that it is combined with the others to convert to columns?

Comment: @user63230 it is just to avoid the dates from conversion to its numeric storage mode.  `lapply` returns a `list`, so there is no issue there, whereas you are combining a vector in to the `list`, which could have some coercion and this could result in Dates to be reconverted again

Comment: what is the difference between `dplyr::first` and `data.table::first`? If I replace `dplyr::first` into your code, I longer need the `all`: `df_dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, dt_names_first, with = FALSE], data.table::first), lapply(.SD[, dt_names_last, with = FALSE], data.table::last),
list(test_date = if(is.na(dplyr::first(test_date[result == "positive"]))) data.table::last(test_date[result == "negative"]) else data.table::first(test_date[result == "positive"]))), .(id)]`

Comment: @user63230 data.table first uses xts or base R head whereas dplyr first uses nth.  So you may have to check the source code of both

Answer (score 2):

```
setDT(df)[
  , .(
    type = type[1], colour = colour[1], x1 = x1[.N], x2 = x2[.N],
    test_date = test_date[match("positive", result, .N)]
  ), id
]
#>    id  type colour x1 x2  test_date
#> 1:  a   car    gre  g  j 1998-01-02
#> 2:  b wheel   dblu  k  x 1998-01-06
#> 3:  c   car    ora  w  o 1998-01-07
```

Comment: thanks, how would you automatically name the variables in this case?

Comment: It's not automatic. Just name the list elements as in the updated answer.