# Incorporating condition into collapse::collap

Tags: r

Is it possible to use `collapse::collap` with a condition?

Given:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(collapse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                 result = c("negative", "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "negative",
                            "positive", "negative", "positive"),
                 test_date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("01/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                                 to = as.Date("09/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), by = "day"),
                 type = c("car", "truck", "bike", "wheel", "tyre", "lorry", "car", "bike", "wheel"),
                 colour = c("gre", "blu", "re", "dblu", "yel", "re", "ora", "ti", "bla"),
                 x1 = sample(letters, 9),
                 x2 = sample(letters, 9))
df
#   id   result  test_date  type colour x1 x2
# 1  a negative 1998-01-01   car    gre  y  u
# 2  a positive 1998-01-02 truck    blu  d  z
# 3  a positive 1998-01-03  bike     re  g  j
# 4  b negative 1998-01-04 wheel   dblu  a  v
# 5  b negative 1998-01-05  tyre    yel  b  n
# 6  b negative 1998-01-06 lorry     re  k  x
# 7  c positive 1998-01-07   car    ora  n  g
# 8  c negative 1998-01-08  bike     ti  r  i
# 9  c positive 1998-01-09 wheel    bla  w  o
```

I want the following output:

```
out_dplyr <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(type, colour), dplyr::first),
            across(c(x1, x2), dplyr::last),
            test_date = if (is.na(dplyr::first(test_date[result == "positive"])))
              dplyr::last(test_date[result == "negative"])
            else dplyr::first(test_date[result == "positive"])) %>% 
  ungroup()
out_dplyr
#   id    type  colour x1    x2    test_date 
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <date>    
# 1 a     car   gre    g     j     1998-01-02
# 2 b     wheel dblu   k     x     1998-01-06
# 3 c     car   ora    w     o     1998-01-07
```

Can this be achieved using `collapse::collap` in one call? The following gets the variables for the last and first calls but I dont know how to incorporate the conditional `test_date` into it.

```
dt_names_first <- c("type", "colour")
dt_names_last <- c("x1", "x2")
collap(df, ~ id, custom = list(ffirst = dt_names_first, flast = dt_names_last))
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first alternative below we encode `result` and `test_date` into `test_date` so that only a single input is needed.  In the second alternative we pass the row numbers so that, again, only a single input is needed.

**1)** Assuming that all dates are > 1970-01-01,

- define `neg_date` as a function which negates dates, i.e. converts dates which are x days after 1970-01-01 to x days before 1970-01-01.
- define `summarize_test` to perform the calculation of `test_date` in the question assuming test_date has been transformed so that negative dates correspond to negative results.

Then we have

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)

neg_date <- function(x) .Date(-as.numeric(x))
summarize_test <- function(x) {
  pos <- x > neg_date(x)
  coalesce(first(x[pos]), last(neg_date(x)[!pos]))
}

df %>%
  mutate(test_date = if_else(result == "positive", 
                              test_date,
                              neg_date(test_date))) %>%
  collap(~ id, custom = list(ffirst = dt_names_first,
                             flast = dt_names_last,
                             summarize_test = "test_date"))
##   id  test_date  type colour x1 x2
## 1  a 1998-01-02   car    gre  g  j
## 2  b 1998-01-06 wheel   dblu  k  x
## 3  c 1998-01-07   car    ora  w  o
```

**2)** A straight forward approach is to number the rows and pass the row numbers to the function which summarizes the test_date.

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)

summarize_test <- function(ix) {
  result <- df$result[ix]
  test_date <- df$test_date[ix]
  pos <- result == "positive"
  coalesce(first(test_date[pos]), last(test_date[!pos]))
}

df %>%
  fmutate(test_date = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  collap(~ id, custom = list(ffirst = dt_names_first,
                             flast = dt_names_last,
                             summarize_test = "test_date")) %>%
  fmutate(test_date = .Date(test_date))
##   id  test_date  type colour x1 x2
## 1  a 1998-01-02   car    gre  g  j
## 2  b 1998-01-06 wheel   dblu  k  x
## 3  c 1998-01-07   car    ora  w  o
```

Comment: Thank you. I was surprised by the slow speed of `collapse` here though. Roughly 15-20 mins on ~8million rows.  This `data.table` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75835148/4083743) was considerably quicker for this case (~2 mins)

Comment: I don't think it can be expected to be fast with custom functions.  Most of the time is likely spent in those functions.  It is only fast when used with built-in collapse functions.